# Move elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm keeping track of a character's position on a game board through the use of a multidimensional array (`board[10][20]`). To allow for user movement, I have created a method, `movePlayer()`, that modifies the value of the index of where 'G' is located.

Whenever I do this, the character 'G' does move, but the previous location of 'G' remains on the gameboard, so there are two 'G's. My question is: How can I move an element (G) in a multidimensional array?

Main Function:

```
char userInput;
int main()
{
    Game obj1;
    cout << "New Game (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    if(userInput == 'y')
    {
        obj1.gameBoard();
        obj2.movePlayer();
    }
}
```

Game(Class).cpp:

```
Game::Game()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10 ; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 20 ; y++)
        {

            board[x][y]= '.';
        }
    }

    player = 'G';
    treasure = 'X';
    srand(time(0));
    p_Pos1X = rand()%10;
    p_Pos1Y = rand()%20;
    t_Pos1X = rand()%10;
    t_Pos1Y = rand()%20;
    endSwitch = 0;

}

void Game::gameBoard()
{
    printBoard(p_Pos1X,p_Pos1Y);
}

void Game::printBoard(int px, int py)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 20 ; y++)
        {
            board[px][py] = player;
            board[t_Pos1X][t_Pos1Y] = treasure;
            cout << board[x][y] ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}


void Game:: movePlayer()
{
    cin >> playerM;
    switch(playerM)
    {
    case 'W':
    case 'w':
        movePlayerUp(p_Pos1X);
    }
}

void Game::movePlayerUp(int m)
{
    m = m - 1;
    printBoard(m,p_Pos1Y);

}
```

Comment: What do you want to be in G's old square? The problem with a single char array is you can't separate terrain from characters or items.

Comment: Id like it to be blank, which would be a '.' So what you're saying is that I need multiple arrays?

Comment: @FelipeZC `My question is: How can I move an element (G) in a multidimensional array(board[10][20])`  Shouldn't you have thought of this rather important piece of information as part of your design, before you wrote any code?

Comment: @FelipeZC - I don't see where you are updating the current position of G.  I see a lot of variables strewn amongst the code that suggests this, but nowhere do I actually see variables being updated when you move an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objetive of the project is not more than a dots matrix and a G reaching a X you dont neds to store a matrix, of course following your approach the code below I hope to be the solution the change is in the printBoard function

```
Game::Game()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10 ; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 20 ; y++)
        {

            board[x][y]= '.';
        }
    }

player = 'G';
treasure = 'X';
srand(time(0));
p_Pos1X = rand()%10;
p_Pos1Y = rand()%20;
t_Pos1X = rand()%10;
t_Pos1Y = rand()%20;
endSwitch = 0;

}

void Game::gameBoard()
{
    printBoard(p_Pos1X,p_Pos1Y);
}

void Game::printBoard(int px, int py)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 20 ; y++)
        {
            if(x==px && y==py) 
            {    
              cout << player ;
            }else if(x== t_Pos1X && y== t_Pos1Y ){
              cout << treasure;
            }else{
              cout << board[x][y] ;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}


void Game:: movePlayer()
{
    cin >> playerM;
    switch(playerM)
    {
    case 'W':
    case 'w':
        movePlayerUp(p_Pos1X);
    }
}

void Game::movePlayerUp(int m)
{
    m = m - 1;
    printBoard(m,p_Pos1Y);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just put a '.' in the player's position just before moving him to the new one?

Comment: This not an answer. If you like, please add that a comment to the OP. No, I did not downvote.